# PHP - Exploding on character(s) that can NEVER be user-defined... How?

Tags: php, string, explode

Ok, am trying to find a character or group of characters, or something that can be used that I can explode from, since the text is user-defined, I need to be able to explode from a value that I have that can never be within the text.

How can I do this?

An example of what I'm trying to do...

```
$value = 'text|0||#fd9||right';
```

Ok,

text is something that should never change in here.
0, again not changeable
`#fd9` is a user-defined string that can be anything that the user inputs...
and right sets the orientation (either left or right).

So, the problem I'm facing is this:  How to `explode("||", $value)` so that if there is a || within the user-defined part...  Example:

```
$value = 'text|0||Just some || text in here||right';
```

So, if the user places the || in the user-defined part of the string, than this messes this up.  How to do this no matter what the user inputs into the string?  So that it should return the following array:

```
array('text|0', 'Just some || text in here', 'right');
```

Should I be using different character(s) to explode from?  If so, what can I use that the user will not be able to input into the string, or how can I check for this, and fix it?  I probably shouldn't be using || in this case, but what can I use to fix this?

Also, the value will be coming from a string at first, and than from the database afterwards (once saved).

Any Ideas?

Comment: What about serialization or a JSON formatted string?

Comment: If you are using something as a delimiter, you *have* to provide a way (escape sequence) if the user actually wants to use that as content (which is why e.g. you need to escape quotes within string literals). It's entirely up to you how to escape that. If you do not, then the best you can do is *guess*, which is not a good position to be in.

Comment: I agree with Jared, JSON or Serialization will definitely be a better way to go about it, then you won't have to worry about what the user enters breaking your code and or coding for a delimiter and escaping.

Comment: Well, the value comes from an XML file at first, cause it installs a plugin, and this value is critical for the plugin to work, since it deals with the parameters for the plugin.  But than the software needs to be able to sort it out, and not sure if JSON or serialization will help.  Can you point me to a link that you think might be helpful perhaps?

Comment: How about CSV and `str_getcsv` with its escaping rules? (meaning double quotes and backslash for the delimiter within, yes the pipe would also be a valid delimiter)

Comment: I would take a look at the [PHP man page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) for JSON, specifically [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). I'm not real sure what you mean by "sort it out", though.

Answer (score 5):

The problem of how to represent arbitrary data types as strings always runs up against exactly the problem you're describing and it has been solved in many ways already. This process is called *serialization* and there are many serialization formats, anything from PHP's native [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) to [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to XML. All these formats specify how to present complex data structures as strings, including *escaping rules* for how to use characters that have a special meaning in the serialization format in the serialized values themselves.

---

From the comments:

> Ok, well, basically, it's straight forward. I already outlined 13 of the other parameters and how they work in Dream Portal located here: http://dream-portal.net/topic_122.0.html so, you can see how they fit in. I'm working on a fieldset parameter that basically uses all of these parameters and than some to include multiple parameters into 1. Anyways, hope that link helps you, for an idea of what an XML file looks like for a module: http://dream-portal.net/topic_98.0.html look at the info.xml section, pay attention to the `<param>` tag in there, at the bottom, 2 of them.

It seems to me that a more sensible use of XML would make this a lot easier. I haven't read the whole thing in detail, but an XML element like

```
<param name="test_param" type="select">0:opt1;opt2;opt3</param>
```

would make much more sense written as

```
<select name="test_param">
    <option default>opt1</option>
    <option>opt2</option>
    <option>opt3</option>
</select>
```

Each unique configuration option can have its own unique element namespace with custom sub-elements depending on the type of parameter you need to represent. Then there's no need to invent a custom mini-format for each possible parameter. It also allows you to create a formal [XML schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) (whether this will do you any good or not is a different topic, but at least you're using XML as it was meant to be used).

Comment: And how do I serialize it?  The entire string should be serialized and unserialized?  Or just the user-defined value?  And if serialized, how does this help within the XML file that sets it's starting value to begin with?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - See here as an example of [JSON encoding and decoding an array](http://codepad.org/EmWYQFWI). It's really pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @solo Have a look at Jared's example. Yes, you serialize the whole array structure as a string. Not sure what you mean by the XML file thing.

Comment: The part I'm unsure about is why the data comes from an XML file, then goes into a variable that's storing an array in string format, only to be converted back to an array later in the script. Why the intermediary step to the delimited string?

Comment: @Jared - the Problem with your example, is that you are starting with an array:  `$arr = array('text', 0, 'Just some || text in here', 'right');` I don't start with an array, just a string value, for example:  `text|0||#fd9||right` and yeah, I notice that your example outputs a string also:  `["text",0,"Just some || text in here","right"]` but how to get it to output it without the `[` and `]` and `"` and `,` characters?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - That was only a demonstration. Where does `text|0||#fd9||right` come from? I'm saying *replace it with a JSON-formatted array*. Is this format out of your control? And the `["",""]` is the JSON format, so it wouldn't be JSON if you removed that.

Comment: @solo Where is this string coming from to begin with? Are you not creating this string? That string is supposed to represent several distinct values, so it is an array in PHP terms. If you are creating that string from several values, use a common, proven *serialization* format. If you are not creating that string and just have to work with what you're getting, it's already ambiguous and foobar'd.

Comment: Or am I understanding it wrong here?  Problem is, I'm starting off with a string, not an array.  The string is coming from an XML file, from a tag in that XML file.  And need to explode 4 things here.  I am setting the standard for this, so can set the text to be anything really, but need `text` `0` `#fd9` and `right` to be within the tags value.  So, really don't even have to use `||`, just thinking that this isn't any different from any other group of characters...

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - We're suggesting that you don't roll your own string array format and use one of the known formats available.

Comment: @solo If you are getting this from an XML file that you are creating to begin with, **use XML properly**. Don't store some custom ambiguous thing in an XML element, store the separate values in separate XML elements. That's exactly what XML is for. `<entry><foo>text</foo><bar>0</bar><baz>#fd9</baz></entry>`

Comment: Ok, so, I need to display information based on the string. than than when it is saved, I need to ONLY change the `#fd9` value within the string to whatever the user inputted into a textbox.  So actually, I need to be able to do both.

Comment: @ Jared, Ok, so I'm following you a bit now.  Use the json string format for this.  Gotcha, and it will be stored in the database as well, should it be serialized before inputting into the database?  And unserialized when retrieved from the database?  And than decode it.  Well, the problem with putting in different tags for this, is that I have so many tags already defined and would rather not have any more.  It's already way too much...

Comment: @solo Use an XML writer to write whatever data structure you want into a custom XML format, *separating separate values into separate XML elements*. Hand the resulting XML string around however you wish. Parse the XML data back into a PHP array using an XML parser. Modify the array. Rinse, repeat. Only use XML (or any other serialized format) if you have to exchange information between systems that can only exchange information via strings. Don't store it in the database. If you have too many tags defined already, maybe you should cut your data down, but don't compromise on the format.

Comment: This is just 1 of 24 other parameters that I have already coded.  They all work, cept this one I'm struggling with.  Not trying to completely rewrite my code from scratch at this point... argg!

Comment: No No, I don't need to write to XML, I read from XML file originally, than when it is saved, it gets stored in the database, and than uses this from that point on to display the values.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - If you're going to be storing the data into a database, can't you use a table with columns for each value? And forget the intermediate format? I suspect you've overcomplicated what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @solo This is getting way out of hand and confusing. Maybe you want to open a new question describing the problem you have in more detail and the problems you have with writing XML files.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - I agree with deceze. Just be sure and provide a procedural description of what is going on each step of the way in the question.

Comment: It's very complicated to say the least.  Would take me several hours to gather pics to explain how all of the information is stored in the database, the XML file, etc. etc..  Honestly, I believe refp answered my question best.  Thanks anyways guys :)

Comment: @solo In my not so humble opinion, if your system is so complicated that a simple data format serialization question would need several hours of background information to be answered properly, your system seems pretty foobar'd... ^_^;;

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - No no no. Not an in-depth, detailed examination. An overview of the process: "User submits request for plugin. Plugin XML is located and default data loaded. User can edit plugin settings, which are then saved to a database." You're overthinking and overanalyzing.

Comment: Ok, well, basically, it's straight forward.  I already outlined 13 of the other parameters and how they work in Dream Portal located here:  http://dream-portal.net/topic_122.0.html so, you can see how they fit in.  I'm working on a fieldset parameter that basically uses all of these parameters and than some to include multiple parameters into 1.  Anyways, hope that link helps you, for an idea of what an XML file looks like for a module:  http://dream-portal.net/topic_98.0.html look at the info.xml section, pay attention to the `<param>` tag in there, at the bottom, 2 of them.

Comment: Wow, gotcha, definitely need to rework that in there... argg! Will need to encase it within a <params> tag ofcourse so the xml knows it's a parameter.  Well, each parameter will need to be thought out differently now.  Definitely more work for me to do on this.

Comment: If I do it this way, than I'll have to define tags for each parameter and than I'll need to sort each parameter differently.  This is way too much work than I need it for... argg!  Cause now I'll need to check each tag within the <parameters> tag for each individual parameter (file_input, text, list_bbc, groups, int, rich_edit, and so many more) and give them all different tags within it, and than use a function to handle the different tags for each parameter.  This is madness!  And way too complicated if you ask me, and too much work than what is needed.

Comment: @solo Huh? Since each type of parameter represents a completely different thing anyway, parsing needs to be customized for each type anyway, no? Lets say you have a `<paramaters>` element that contains various elements like `<select>`. You'd just go through them with something like `foreach ($xml->parameters as $param)` and `switch ($param->name) { case 'select' : parseSelectParameter($param); ... }`. You should have something like this in place anyway, no? I don't see how writing it differently makes that much more work.

Comment: Well, currently, I am reading each <param> tag and just doing a simple edit to it depending on what type it is.  If I make this change, there will be more than a simple edit, we are talking about reading tons of tags here...

Comment: @solo Well, obviously I can't decide that for you. To answer your specific question though, you should properly define your XML schema and use it, that solves the problem you have with data escaping. Looking at what your project is apparently trying to do (very freeform configurable forum), I would not expect to be able to do this without properly defined data structures and however much code is necessary to properly parse them. I'd even create individual classes for each possible parameter for proper abstraction, otherwise it seems like the project complexity would just explode.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode any user input to base64 and then use it with explode or however you wish.

```
print base64_encode("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[];,./?>:}{<");
```

serialized arrays are also not a bad idea at all. it's probably better than using a comma separated string and explode. Drupal makes good use of serialized arrays.

take a look at the PHP manual on how to use it:

- [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: New Solution**

Is it a guarantee that `text` doesn't contain `||` itself?
If it doesn't, you can use `substr()` in combination with `strpos()` and `strrpos()` instead of explode

---

Here's what I usually do to get around this problem.

1) capture user's text and save it in a var `$user_text`;

2) run an `str_replace()` on `$user_text` to replace the characters you want to split by:

```
//replace with some random string the user would hopefully never enter 
$modified = str_replace('||','{%^#',$user_text);
```

3) now you can safely `explode` your text using `||`

4) now run an `str_replace` on each part of the explode, to set it back to the original user entered text

```
foreach($parts as &$part) {
    $part = str_replace('{%^#','||',$part);
}
```

Comment: Technically this is no improvement at all. `||` is *already* "some random string the user would hopefully never enter".

Comment: You're just going 'round in circles with `some random string the user would hopefully never enter`.

Comment: `Is it a guarantee that text doesn't contain || itself?` No, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: I meant `text` as in `text is something that should never change in here` that you described in your question, not the user entered part. Sorry for the confusion.